# USB tethering: Allow only wifi

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, wifi-tethering, mobile-data

I want to connect my computer to my wifi network. As it does not have a wifi module I use my phone (Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2) to tether its wifi connection via USB.

When my phone looses the connection to the wifi or I forget to turn it on when I come home my computer uses up my phones mobile data, which I obviously don't like.

So the question is: Is there a (native?) way to limit USB tethering to the wifi connection?

Comment: This all sounds very complicated when USB Wi-Fi modules cost less than ten pounds.

Comment: It isn't complicated at all - I connect my phone, click on a shortcut and am ready... My phone's lying on my desk all the time anyway, so why by more hardware instead of using the one that's available.
I now just disable mobile data when USB tethering is activated, this shouldn't be necessary though.